# Does MapReduce need to be use with HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to make a better performance for data processing using Hadoop MapReduce. So, do I need to use it along with Hadoop DFS? Or maybe MapReduce can be use with other type of data distributed? Show me the way, please....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadoop is a framework which includes Map Reduce programming model for computation and HDFS for storage.

HDFS stands for hadoop distributed file system which is inspired from Google File System. The overall Hadoop project is inspired based on the research paper published by Google.

[research.google.com/archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf)

http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html

Using Map Reduce programming model data will be computed in parallel way in different nodes across the cluster which will decrease the processing time.

You need to use HDFS or HBASE to store your data in the cluster to get the high performance. If you like to choose normal file system, then there will not be much difference. Once the data goes to distributed system, automatically it will be divided across different block and replicated by default 3 times to avoid fault tolerance. All these will not be possible with normal file system

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful. Just I need to read more to really understand about it. Btw, refer on your statement that stated HDFS or HBASE are needed to store the data to get the high performance effect. Is there any journal or website that thoroughly explain about this? TQSM! @Data-KeeG

Comment: @KrengKongkeng https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/  can you accept the answer please?

Comment: hehe yes.. gladly to accept it.. but i hope that you don't mind if there's anything else that I will ask you here :D

Comment: @KrengKongkeng not at all

Answer (score 2):

First, your idea is wrong. Performance of Hadoop MapReduce is not directly related to the performance of HDFS. It is considered to be slow because of its architecture:

1. It processes data with Java. Each separate mapper and reducer is a separate instance of JVM, which need to be invoked, which takes some time
2. It puts intermediate data on the HDDs many times. At minimum, mappers write their results (one), reducers reads and merges them, writing result set to disks (two), reducer results written back to your filesystem, usually HDFS (three). You can find more details on the process here: http://0x0fff.com/hadoop-mapreduce-comprehensive-description/.

Second, Hadoop is open framework and it supports many different filesystems. You can read data from FTP, S3, local filesystem (NFS share, for instance), MapR-FS, IBM GPFS, GlusterFS by RedHat, etc. So you are free to choose the one you like. The main idea for MapReduce is to specify InputFormat and OutputFormat that would be able to work with your filesystem

Spark at the moment is considered to be a faster replacement of the Hadoop MapReduce as it puts much of the computations to the memory. But its use really depends on your case